# Mockito @Spy on fields of the same type

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

I have the following unit test where I have the below mock and spies.

```
@Spy
private Map<String, String> rulesObjects = new HashMap<>();

@Spy
private Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> mandatoryFieldObject = new HashMap<>();

@Mock
private configProperties configProperties;

@InjectMocks
private LoaderService loaderService;

@Test
@DisplayName("This test should load the config files in memory")
void initRuleMaps() throws IOException {
    this.loaderService.initRuleMaps();
    assertThat(this.rulesObjects)
            .isNotEmpty()
            .hasSize(3);
}
```

The logic for initRuleMaps calls these 2 methods;

```
private void saveRulesInCache() throws IOException {
    rulesObjects.put(EmvcoConstants.LEGACY, dataLegacy);
    rulesObjects.put(EmvcoConstants.LEGACY1, dataLegacy1);
    rulesObjects.put(EmvcoConstants.LEGACY2, dataLegacy2);
}

private void saveMandatoryFieldListInCache() throws IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> type: this.configProperties.getTypes().entrySet()) {
        Map<String, List<String>> mandatoryRuleFiledMap = getMandatoryRuleFiled(qrType.getKey());
        mandatoryFieldObject.put(type.getValue(), mandatoryRuleFiledMap);
    }

}
```

In the method initRuleMaps, there was some computations on both maps. Each one should have 3 entries. But what's happening it seems only one spy has been created and all computations are being done on one object only. Hence I am getting 6 entries.

When looking at the reference of each spy, they are the same actually.

Is there any way around this?

Thank you.

Comment: It hard to tell without seeing code of `initRuleMaps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your problem lies with `@InjectMocks` which can't differentiate between the two map: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

> Field injection; mocks will first be resolved by type (if a single
> type match injection will happen regardless of the name), then, if
> there is several property of the same type, by the match of the field
> name and the mock name.
>
> Note 1: If you have fields with the same type (or same erasure), it's
> better to name all @Mock annotated fields with the matching fields,
> otherwise Mockito might get confused and injection won't happen.
>
> Note 2: If @InjectMocks instance wasn't initialized before and have a
> no-arg constructor, then it will be initialized with this constructor.

I think your problem lies in the erasure (the two fields does have the same type: `Map`).

You should try naming the Mock/Spy: `@Mock(name = "database")` with the name being the same as the field found in the `@InjectMocks`.

Alternatively, create a constructor and do it yourself: `new LoaderService(rulesObjects, mandatoryFieldObject, configProperties)`.

Comment: yes agree. Created a new constructor. Thanks. Only mock has the attribute name not spy though.